# Flutter 1.9: D/skia ( 5106): Shader compilation error

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

I've created a simple Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.4 application using Android Studio 3.5.1. After adding successfully a new virtual device (Nexus 6) and tried to run my app, I got this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/EGL_emulation( 5106): eglMakeCurrent: 0xec5ed840: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xec593810)
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106): 
D/skia    ( 5106): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 5106): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 5106): Errors:
D/skia    ( 5106):
```

The application runs correctly but the console shows the errors above.

**My Configuration:**

> Android Studio 3.5.1
>
> Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203, built on September 25, 2019
>
> JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64
>
> JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>
> Windows 10 Pro 64bits

Answer (score 106):

I solved my `Shader compilation error` by changing emulator's settings.

Press that `...` button which is located on the side panel of emulator, and go to Settings section. There, go to Advanced tab and change OpenGL ES API level to `Compatibility (OpenGL ES 1.1/2.0)`.

Do not forget to close and rerun the emulator after this change. On the first run, emulator could pop a warning on its screen and it would take a while to get ready, but do not worry.

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer. Thank you so much

Comment: This is the proper solution

Comment: Accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

The error message comes from: [Add ShaderErrorHandler to GrContextOptions](https://github.com/google/skia/commit/5e7fbfd9b0d6737e08ee9d8861c30ebc244396df)

In the previous Flutter versions, the persistent cache had been disabled to remedy the problem. However, it is currently enabled in the Fllutter engine:
[Revert "Disable the persistent cache](https://github.com/flutter/engine/commit/2f87713d4074afe4970ae55256100b50819d5315)

**Possible solutions**:

- Downgrade your Flutter version to the linked commit
- Enable rendering `flutter run --enable-software-rendering`
- Disable hardware acceleration in the emulator

**Issue**:

[8578 Shader compilation error](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33018)

Comment: I added `--enable-software-rendering` to [Edit Configurations...] > [Additional arguments] and it fixed. Flutter v1.12

Comment: @TheTahaan Downgrading and avoiding hardware acceleration isn't a very sustainable solution. The root cause of the issue has been fixed in the meantime. In my case, a flutter clean did the trick (which may have been necessary because my emulator had crashed before).

Answer (score 16):

Open the terminal, Navigate to your folder and

Type `flutter run --enable-software-rendering` after that debug and run again.

This worked for me and it might help you too!

Comment: This is a temporary solution, if you use this option, you have to hot reload again and again. Sorry rangerboyy...

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same issue.Use flutter clean and then run the app. This fixed mine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, once I wrapped the widget in Scaffold , the problem is solved.

Comment: I wrapped it with **Scaffold**

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me when I tested in Emulator. My `Emulated Performance` used to set to `Automatic`, which in my case it runs using `Hardware - GLES 2.0`. Changing it to `Software - GLES 2.0` solves this issue.

Where to find the setting:
Open Android Studio, open AVD manager, click the edit icon that looks like a pencil on your virtual device. There you'll find this setting.

Answer (score 1):

Please add --enable-software-rendering to

```
[Edit Configurations...] > [Additional arguments]
```

and it should be fixed

Comment: Android Studio > Run > Edit Configurations > Additional run args: --enable-software-rendering

Answer (score 0):

it happened because of your emulator, run the app on a real device, then run it again on your emulator.
I did that, and fix my problem.

Comment: What specifically about the emulator caused the issue?
Why would running the app "on a real device" fix it?

Can you add any insight into this solution?

Comment: I just tested it, and i don't know reason why -_-

Comment: This is not a helpful answer, running it on a real device does not fix the issue on the emulator.

Comment: in my case , this fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe following technique works:
If you are using android studio there are one test folder. In that folder if you click on auto solve option it create one class what is causing error. In my case it was myapp() and it is solved. maybe it works.
Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

My code was **4170** shader compilation error,

I solved that by just moving the fonts folder of ( the custom fonts specifically icons as they also are the same ) at the root directory.
The path should look like this-

```
fonts:
     - family: MyIconClass
       fonts:
           - asset: fonts/myIcons.ttf
```

Answer (score 0):

Open `Emulator(SDKPHONE)` , Going to ... button at bottom ([image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV7at.png)) => `Settings` section => go to `Advanced tab` and change both to `Auto` ([image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xppxA.png)). `Choosing Direct X 11 and other settings would take more memory space`. Changing Open GL ES renderer to Angle DX 11, Open GS EL API level to Render maximum 3.1 will also work but it will take up more memory space. Hence it's better to select auto.

`Note: first of all you must confirm that flutter is fully updated with plugins(dart and flutter).`

After that `disconnect your emulator`  from `studio`, `close the emulator`,   `restart your emulator` and `build your apk`. Hope this will work fine.

Comment: Need edit, unclear