# how to resolve "Shader compilation error " in android emulator when using flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

when i use Android Studio 3.5 and dart 2.5 (i used flutter for develop mobile app) ,I faced to "Shader compilation error" in android emulator.
I have no error with my code .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter 1.9: D/skia ( 5106): Shader compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380329/flutter-1-9-d-skia-5106-shader-compilation-error)

Comment: yes it is the problem ,thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow it worked on my side,

removed / uninstall the app in emulator

flutter clean

run again

Comment: it keeps coming back again!

Answer (score 0):

for me flutter clean in terminal makes it go away