# How to solve this error while integrating Google pay in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, payment, google-pay

I know it's a basic question but it is taking way long time to solve this. I'm trying to integrate google pay using Pay package , I've followed the instructions still this error is showing up:
[image]

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380329/flutter-1-9-d-skia-5106-shader-compilation-error
and see if it will solve the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter 1.9: D/skia ( 5106): Shader compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380329/flutter-1-9-d-skia-5106-shader-compilation-error)