# Can't use google maps in PageView

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I'm using google maps in a `PageView` widget, but I get a huge-text error that I can't solve. Any help, please!
[image]

This is the dart file that contains the `PageView` widget:

```
import '/core/themes/colors.dart';
import '/core/components/custom_bottom_navigation_bar.dart';
import '/core/components/custom_loader.dart';
import 'components/custom_app_bar.dart';
import 'components/ads_in_overview.dart';
import 'components/ads_in_map.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'home';
  HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final PageController pageController = PageController();
  int currentPage = 0;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    pageController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //TODO: there is a custom drawer for filters opened from the search icon button in the custom app bar (not designed yet)
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar(),
        body: PageView(
          controller: pageController,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          allowImplicitScrolling: false,
          children: [
            AdsInMap(),
            AdsInOverview(),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            pageController.animateToPage(
              currentPage == 0 ? 1 : 0,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              curve: Curves.easeInOut,
            );
            setState(() {
              currentPage = currentPage == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            });
          },
          label: Icon(
            currentPage == 0
                ? Icons.format_list_bulleted
                : Icons.location_on_outlined,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colours.kAccentColor,
          foregroundColor: Colours.kPrimaryColor,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: const CustomBottomNavigationBar(
          selectedTabItemIndex: 0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The google maps is in `AdsInMap` widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import 'package:toggle_switch/toggle_switch.dart';

import '/core/themes/colors.dart';

class AdsInMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const AdsInMap({super.key});

  @override
  State<AdsInMap> createState() => _AdsInMapState();
}

class _AdsInMapState extends State<AdsInMap> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{
  int toggleButtonIndex = 0;

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  //TODO: remove fake data when loading from an API
  //TODO: the custom marker needs changes
  Set<Marker> customMarkers = {};
  GoogleMapController? controller;

  /*Future<void> initCustomMarkers() async {
    final jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/fake_data/ads.json');
    final json = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    final ads = json['listings'];
    Set<Marker> newCustomMarkers = {};
    if(context.mounted){
      for (Map<String, dynamic> ad in ads) {
        MoneyFormatter formatter = MoneyFormatter(
          amount: (ad['price'] as int).toDouble(),
          settings: MoneyFormatterSettings(
              compactFormatType: CompactFormatType.short),
          locale: context.locale,
        );
        debugPrint('start creating markers');
        newCustomMarkers.addLabelMarker(
          LabelMarker(
            label: formatter.output.compactNonSymbol,
            markerId: MarkerId('${ad['id']}'),
            position: LatLng(ad['location']['lat'], ad['location']['lng']),
          ),
        );
        *//*customMarkers.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('${ad['id']}'),
          position: LatLng(ad['location']['lat'], ad['location']['lng']),
          icon: await CustomMarkerIcon(
            price: formatter.output.compactNonSymbol,
          ).toBitmapDescriptor(
            logicalSize: const Size(1000, 350),
            imageSize: const Size(1000, 350),
          ),
        ),
      );*//*
      }
      setState(() {
        customMarkers = newCustomMarkers;
      });
    }
  }*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        //TODO: edit this to be a PageView
        GoogleMap(
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          zoomControlsEnabled: false,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(
              24.774265,
              46.738586,
            ),
            zoom: 12.0,
          ),
          onMapCreated: ((mapController) {
            setState(() {
              controller = mapController;
            });
          }),
          markers: {},
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 20.0,
          left: 8.w,
          child: ToggleSwitch(
            minWidth: 28.w,
            minHeight: AppBar().preferredSize.height,
            fontSize: 14.sp,
            initialLabelIndex: toggleButtonIndex,
            dividerColor: Colours.kPrimaryColor,
            activeBgColor: const [Colours.kAccentColor],
            activeFgColor: Colours.kPrimaryColor,
            inactiveBgColor: Colours.kPrimaryColor,
            inactiveFgColor: Colours.kAccentColor,
            centerText: true,
            totalSwitches: 3,
            labels: [
              tr('main.home.sale'),
              tr('main.home.rent'),
              tr('main.home.daily'),
            ],
            onToggle: (index) {},
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible code sample? There's not much to work off here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more an emulator issue because it's giving a shader error. Looks much similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380329/flutter-1-9-d-skia-5106-shader-compilation-error#:%7E:text=I%20solved%20my,do%20not%20worry.).

> Press that ... button which is located on the side panel of emulator,
> and go to Settings section. There, go to Advanced tab and change
> OpenGL ES API level to Compatibility (OpenGL ES 1.1/2.0).

Try out the solutions and give me your feedback.