# Flutter - svg from figma is having an error

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

The task is use the svg from figma to be use in flutter. but there is error showing in terminal but the image is showing.

Its working fine when running in web but in android its showing this error.

I try this solution find in internet but not working.

Move the `<defs>` up, as the first children in the `<svg>` element
link: https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/102

And this one is by changing the emulator OpenGL
link: [Flutter 1.9: D/skia ( 5106): Shader compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380329/flutter-1-9-d-skia-5106-shader-compilation-error)

Dependency

```
flutter_svg: ^2.0.9
```

Code

```
 Widget _buildBackgroundImage(BuildContext context,String filename) {
    return Container(
      // color: Colors.black,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      
      child: SvgPicture.asset(
        'assets/images/sample.svg',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,

      ),

    );
  }
```

Error

```
D/skia    (15939): Shader compilation error
D/skia    (15939): ------------------------
D/skia    (15939):    1 #version 300 es
D/skia    (15939):    2 
D/skia    (15939):    3 #extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require
D/skia    (15939):    4 precision mediump float;
D/skia    (15939):    5 precision mediump sampler2D;
D/skia    (15939):    6 const mediump float sk_PrivkGuardedDivideEpsilon = false ? 1e-08 : 0.0;
D/skia    (15939):    7 inout mediump vec4 sk_FragColor;
D/skia    (15939):    8 uniform highp vec4 uclamp_S1_c0_c0;
D/skia    (15939):    9 uniform highp mat3 umatrix_S1_c0;
D/skia    (15939):   10 uniform sampler2D uTextureSampler_0_S1;
D/skia    (15939):   11 flat in mediump vec4 vcolor_S0;
D/skia    (15939):   12 in highp vec2 vTransformedCoords_3_S0;
D/skia    (15939):   13 mediump float f_Qhh2h2(mediump vec2 a, mediump vec2 b);
D/skia    (15939):   14 mediump float f_Qhh2h2(mediump vec2 a, mediump vec2 b) {
D/skia    (15939):   15     if (2.0 * a.x <= a.y) {
D/skia    (15939):   16         return (((b.x * b.x) * (a.y - 2.0 * a.x)) / (b.y + sk_PrivkGuardedDivideEpsilon) + (1.0 - b.y) * a.x) + b.x * ((-a.y + 2.0 * a.x) + 1.0);
D/skia    (15939):   17     } else if (4.0 * b.x <= b.y) {
D/skia    (15939):   18         mediump float c = b.x * b.x;
D/skia    (15939):   19         mediump float e = c * b.x;
D/skia    (15939):   20         mediump float f = b.y * b.y;
D/skia    (15939):   21         mediump float g = f * b.y;
D/skia    (15939):   22         return (((f * (a.x - b.x * ((3.0 * a.y - 6.0 * a.x) - 1.0)) + ((12.0 * b.y) * c) * (a.y - 2.0 * a.x)) - (16.0 * e) * (a.y - 2.0 * a.x)) - g * a.x) / (f + sk_PrivkGuardedDivideEpsilon);
D/skia    (15939):   23     } else {
D/skia    (15939):   24         return ((b.x * ((a.y - 2.0 * a.x) + 1.0) + a.x) - sqrt(b.y * b.x) * (a.y - 2.0 * a.x)) - b.y * a.x;
D/skia    (15939):   25     }
D/skia    (15939):   26 }
D/skia    (15939):   27 void main() {
D/skia    (15939):   28     mediump vec4 outputColor_S0 = vcolor_S0;
D/skia    (15939):   29     mediump vec4 _8_input = outputColor_S0;
D/skia    (15939):   30     highp vec2 _9_inCoord = vTransformedCoords_3_S0;
D/skia    (15939):   31     highp vec2 _10_subsetCoord;
D/skia    (15939):   32     _10_subsetCoord.x = _9_inCoord.x;
D/skia    (15939):   33     _10_subsetCoord.y = _9_inCoord.y;
D/skia    (15939):   34     highp vec2 _11_clampedCoord = clamp(_10_subsetCoord, uclamp_S1_c0_c0.xy, uclamp_S1_c0_c0.zw);
D/skia    (15939):   35     mediump vec4 _12_textureColor = texture(uTextureSampler_0_S1, _11_clampedCoord, -0.475);
D/skia    (15939):   36     _8_input = _12_textureColor;
D/skia    (15939):   37     mediump vec4 output_S1 = _8_input;
D/skia    (15939):   38     {
D/skia    (15939):   39         mediump vec4 _dstColor = sk_FragColor;
D/skia    (15939):   40         sk_FragColor = _dstColor.w == 0.0 ? output_S1 : vec4(f_Qhh2h2(output_S1.xw, _dstColor.xw), f_Qhh2h2(output_S1.yw, _dstColor.yw), f_Qhh2h2(output_S1.zw, _dstColor.zw), output_S1.w + (1.0 - output_S1.w) * _dstColor.w);
D/skia    (15939):   41     }
D/skia    (15939):   42 }
D/skia    (15939):   43 
D/skia    (15939): Errors:
D/skia    (15939): ERROR: 0:7: 'inout' : invalid qualifier: can be only used with function parameters
D/skia    (15939):
```

Comment: Disregard this question, i just change the android emulator to android 11